# How can i Reset my Timer value meanwhile completion of timer?

Tags: java, android, timer, counter, countdown

I am trying to start a timer when activity created and be able to reset the timer back from zero if the same button is pressed but every time I press the button that initiates the set Interval it seems to be creating a new interval and not resetting the one that was already creating. Can someone help please? Here is my code

```
timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer_value);

Count = new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            timer.setText("Time Left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            timer.setText("OUT OF TIME!");
            if (time < 10000) {
                time = 10000;
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    TicTacToe.this);
            builder.setMessage("You are Out of Time").setPositiveButton(
                    "Replay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // reset the game environment.

                            Count.onFinish();
                            // Count.cancel();
                            Count.start();
                            new_game(player_name_1);
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use timers

```
//in global
Timer myTimer


/**
* its kills runnable
*/
public void stopTimer(){
//handler.removeCallbacks(null); //it resets all timer which handler holds
myTimer.cancel();
}

public void setTimer(int time){//give it 5 for 5 secs
final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            //do sth
        }
    };

    myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimerTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, 1000, time*1000);
}
```

Comment: but i have a specified time for countDownTimer how can i implement that and as my question how to stop and reset timer value in between timer completion and reset the value of timer . Can you help me now @alp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restart your timer, remove `Count.onFinish();`

**Update:**
I replaced AlertDialog with a new thread and here is the code that works on my emulator

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    int time = 10000;
    CountDownTimer Count;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);

        Count = new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                timer.setText("Time Left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                timer.setText("OUT OF TIME!");
                if (time < 10000) {
                    time = 100000;
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
    public void buttonClicked(View view)
    {
        Log.i("Timer", "Resetting timer");
        Count.cancel();
        Count.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: but its not working its generating a new timer with different value and i have remove that but its not working

Comment: let me check i will let you know

Comment: But @helleye as i have asked question is that i wanna restart it from zero before completion of timer using button click . Please think about this and thanks for your help but its not my problem for which "The solution you have provided me "

Comment: What do you mean by "restart it from zero"? If it starts to count down like 10, 9, 8.. and at that time if you press a button to set it to 0 and to stop counting or?

Comment: "restart it from zero" means the defined value which is 10 for me

Comment: Then when the button is pressed, call `Count.cancel(); Count.start();` On my test app for this, it worked like you expected.

Comment: i have did this but its not working a copy of counter value is created every time

Comment: Could you please join this chat room so that I can get more details about your issue?
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52665/reset-timer-value